# Sandbox to prod getcontentaspdf not working

Tags: apex, pdf

I have everything working normally in my sandbox (render as pdf on a vf page), but when I copied everything and paste inside my prod, I have a pdf that look likes this when I render it as pdf

[image]

If I don't render it as pdf, I have something weird at the beginning of the page :

```
    <script src="/static/111213/js/perf/stub.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>(function(UITheme) {
    UITheme.getUITheme = function() { 
        return UserContext.uiTheme;
    };
}(window.UITheme = window.UITheme || {}));</script><meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="Mon, 01 Jan 1990 12:00:00 GMT" />
```

If instead of calling the page from a method with getcontentaspdf, I go directly to the page and use renderas pdf, then it is working.

THe problem comes from getcontentaspdf. I am system admin on the system. Is there any others rights I need to set up ?

Comment: Have you tried deploying the VF page with a change set?

Comment: Not possible as My sandbox was part of another salesforce environment. I am creating everything like its new

Comment: Since your environment isn't a copy of their environment, you need to  create a sandbox in their org and test the page there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Needed for chrome to add  `applicationpdf.ContentType = 'application/pdf';`

instead of  `applicationpdf.ContentType = '.pdf';`